# Hack into Beamer page (or frame) numbers

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I use `pause` and `only` in my presentation.
Currently, I got 3 identical number `29/38` for three pages where I use
`pause` and `only`. (I don't know exact what command or setting I use).

I would like to have `29-1/38` `29-2/38` and `29-3/38`
to distinguish these three pages, or anything which can make the distinction.
I DON'T want to use `29`, `30` and `31`, because this lose the information
that these
three pages are in fact the same (updated) "frame".

Here is the MWE whose setting is used in my actual

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\only<1,2,3>{a}
\pause
\only<2,3>{b}
\pause
\only<3>{c}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there any hack way to customize the page/frame numbers for some specific pages. I won't mind a solution that will require me to modify manually the number for each page of the whole document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "number of overlays" can be calculated by the difference of the startpage of a frame and the current page number.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{centering}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
            \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}
}

\newcounter{cont}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber%
            \setcounter{cont}{\thepage}%
                \addtocounter{cont}{1}%
                \addtocounter{cont}{-\beamer@startpageofframe}%
            \ifnum\beamer@startpageofframe=\beamer@endpageofframe%
            \else%
                -\arabic{cont}%
              \fi%
             ~/ \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't study this code yet, but it works! Thank you.

Comment: However, there is some minor issue: I get `2-4`, `2-5` and `2-6`. But I would like to have `2-1`, `2-2` and `2-3`. Also, the number after `/` is always `1`, which is not right. It should be the total number of  frames `2` in your example.

Comment: @user565739 Strange! For example for the last page I get `2-3 / 2`. Have you compiled more than once? Or tried to delete the auxiliary files? [I just noticed another problem: on frames without `\pause` commands, you probably do not want 2-1 but simply 2?]

Comment: Fixed for frames without overlays

Comment: Thank you. It works as what I want now. I won't look at the details of your code at this moment (I need to defense my thesis soon). Maybe later.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck with your defence!